# Eclipse not detecting mobile device connected to it.

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to run my android project in device. My device is not detecting in Eclipse. When I connected with USB cable in Eclipse. I restarted Eclipse and I have checked USB debugging on the device. Can anybody tell what is problem and how to resolve it?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Comment: check in device manager if android USB device  drivers is exist if not update the software driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Main issues causing this problem problems could be,

- Check whether the USB Debugging mode is enabled in the device.
- Whether the device drivers are installed.
- Might some of the device drivers needs to be updated.

To resolve these issues,

- USB Debugging option could be accessed at, **Settings > Applications > Development**.
- for installing device drivers, go to **Device Manager->USB device->Update Drivers**.